# Fetching PR status, comments, etc. from github API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to fetch PR status/comments using the github API. Two examples issues:

- https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/pull/950
- https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget/pull/1545

I can get the original PR data via the API by GETting these resources:

- https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/pull/950
- https://api.github.com/repos/okta/okta-signin-widget/issues/1545

But then I want to find information that these changes were approved, any comments, and the timestamp of those actions, etc. (e.g. "foo approved these changes" and "good catch! thanks for the submission. We'll get this merged.")

I've read the docs and tried following the resources returns from the API, but nothing. I thought the `pull_request` resource would be useful:

```
"pull_request": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/okta/okta-signin-widget/pulls/1545
}
```

But I can still find nothing. I'm sure it's there... Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I looked on the github API forums and found my answer:

It's the `reviews` resource:

`https://api.github.com/repos/okta/okta-signin-widget/pulls/1545/reviews`